# Incremental text markers

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, labels

I want incremental markers on text that I can reference afterwards.
I'm building a index of limitations so something like this would be nice:

```
\limitation{limitationInternalIdentifier}
```

So in its occurence it would show something like `LIMITATION 1`.

And if I reference it in another place:

```
\ref{limitation:limitationInternalIdentifier}
```

It would display `LIMITATION 1` as well.

Do you have some idea of how to accomplish that? It doesn't need to be exactly like this; something similar that ends in the same result is ok.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer a starter document actually.

Comment: **fancyref** would work for the reference. Just a simple counter for the labelling.

Comment: Or `cleveref` would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Using an autolabelling way and `\Cref` or `\cref` to let LaTeX know it's a `limitation` label. `cleveref` needs to know that the `limitation` counter should be referred to as `Limitiation` or `LIMITATION`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{limitation}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\limitationname}{LIMITATION}
\newcommand{\limitation}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{limitation}%
  \limitationname\ \thelimitation.%
  \label{limitation:#1}%
}

\crefname{limitation}{limitation}{limitations}
\Crefname{limitation}{LIMITATION}{LIMITATIONS}


\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

\limitation{foo}

\blindtext[1]


\limitation{foobar}

In \Cref{limitation:foo} we saw that ... however in \Cref{limitation:foobar} it was shown that...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using **fancyref**. For reasons which need not concern us here, I prefer **fancyref** to **cleverref**. (But note that my impression is that I am in a minority.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\newcounter{limitation}
\newcommand*\limitation[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{limitation}LIMITATION \thelimitation\label{limitation:#1}}
\newcommand*{\fancyreflimitationlabelprefix}{limitation}
\fancyrefaddcaptions{english}{%
  \newcommand*{\Freflimitationname}{Limitation}%
  \newcommand*{\freflimitationname}{%
    \MakeLowercase{\Freflimitationname}}}
\frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflimitationlabelprefix}{{\freflimitationname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\Frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflimitationlabelprefix}{{\Freflimitationname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\frefformat{plain}{\fancyreflimitationlabelprefix}{{\freflimitationname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\Frefformat{plain}{\fancyreflimitationlabelprefix}{{\Freflimitationname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\begin{document}

\limitation{limitationInternalIdentifier}

\Fref{limitation:limitationInternalIdentifier}

\fref{limitation:limitationInternalIdentifier}

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier references]